# Drupal: sidebar only shown on build/block page

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-theming

I added a sidebar to my admin theme in Drupal. The sidebar is shown correctly on the /admin/build/block/list/* pages but not in the other pages.

I am using the fubik theme, a theme close to rubik but with the ability to display sidebars.

I checked the page.tpl.php page, and it seems the $left variable is empty (on the pages that are not /admin/build/block/list/* pages), but I set two blocks to be displayed in that sidebar.

Am I missing a configuration step?

Answer (score 0):

1. All the regions will be shown in `admin/build/block/list/* pages` irrespective of whether they have any content(any blocks). ie even if there is no content to be shown these blocks will be highlighted and shown.
2. Whereas in other pages, the regions will only be shown if they have some content to be shown.

In your case though you have enabled the blocks it is not being shown, the reason may be that `the blocks you have enabled don't have any content in them.`
Try putting some blocks with static content.

Even then if it doesn't show up, then may be `you are enabling the blocks in the wrong theme`. Make sure that you are enabling them in the right theme.

Comment: Thanks, but the blocks do have content (it can be seen on the admin/build/block/list/* pages), and it is the correct theme that is being used (I checked in the code, and tried hard-coding the theme that is used).